# Perl - convert hexadecimal to binary and use it as string

Tags: perl, type-conversion, hex, bin

I am new to Perl and I have difficulties using the different types.

I am trying to get an hexadecimal register, transform it to binary, use it a string and get substrings from the binary string.

I have done a few searches and what I tried is :

```
my $hex = 0xFA1F;
print "$hex\n";
```

result was "64031" . First surprise : can't I print the hex value in Perl and not just the decimal value ?

```
$hex = hex($hex);
print "$hex\n";
```

Result was 409649. Second surprise : I would expect the result to be also 64031 since "hex" converts hexadecimal to decimal.

```
my $bin = printf("%b", $hex);
```

It prints the binary value. Is there a way to transform the hex to bin without printing it ?

Thanks,
SLP

Comment: Try adding quotes around the hex constant: `my $hex ='0xFA1F'`. If not it will be converted to the number 64031. Later, when you do `hex(64031)`, 64031 is interpreted as the hexadecimal string `0x64031`

Comment: Thanks ! very simple indeed... it works for me

Answer (score 4):

Decimal, binary, and hexadecimal are all *text representations* of a number (i.e. ways of *writing* a number). Computers can't deal with these as numbers.

`my $num = 0xFA1F;` stores the specified number (sixty-four thousand and thirty-one) into `$num`. It's stored in a format the hardware understands, but that's not very important. What's important is that it's stored as a number, not text.

When `print` is asked to print a number, it prints it out in decimal (or scientific notation if large/small enough). It has no idea how the number of created (from a hex constant? from addition? etc), so it can't determine how to output the number based on that.

To print an number as hex, you can use

```
my $hex = 'FA1F';   # $hex contains the hex representation of the number.
print $hex;         # Prints the hex representation of the number.
```

or

```
my $num = 0xFA1F;   # $num contains the number.
printf "%X", $num;  # Prints the hex representation of the number.
```

Comment: As a side note, Perl can deal with the decimal representation of a number as if it was a number. If a string is about to be used in a numerical operation, Perl will first convert the string from decimal to a number. This isn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a integer value using hexadecimal format. `print` by default prints numbers in decimal format, so you are getting 64031.

You can verify this using the printf() by giving different formats.

```
$ perl -e ' my $num = 0xFA1F; printf("%d %X %b\n", ($num) x 3 ) '
64031 FA1F 1111101000011111

$ perl -e ' my $num = 64031; printf("%d %X %b\n", ($num) x 3 ) '
64031 FA1F 1111101000011111

$ perl -e ' my $num = 0b1111101000011111; printf("%d %X %b\n", ($num) x 3 ) '
64031 FA1F 1111101000011111

$
```

To get the binary format of 0xFA1F in string, you can use sprintf()

```
$ perl -e ' my $hex = 0xFA1F; my $bin=sprintf("%b",$hex) ; print "$bin\n" '
1111101000011111

$
```

Answer (score 2):

lets take each bit of confusion in order

```
my $hex = 0xFA1F;
```

This stores a hex constant in `$hex`, but Perl doesn't have a hex data type so although you can write hex constants, and binary and octal constants for that matter, Perl converts them all to decimal. Note that there is a big difference between

```
my $hex = 0xFA1F;
```

and

```
my $hex = '0xFA1F';
```

The first stores a number into $hex, which when you print it out you get a decimal number, the second stores a string which when printed out will give `0xFAF1` but can be passed to the `hex()` function to be converted to decimal.

```
$hex = hex($hex);
```

The hex function converts a *string* as if it was a hex number and returns the decimal value and, as up to this point, `$hex` has only ever been used as a number Perl will first stringify `$hex` then pass the string to the `hex()` function to convert that value from hex to decimal.

So to the solution. You are almost there with `printf()`,there is a function called `sprintf()` which takes the same parameters as `printf()` but instead of printing the formatted value returns it as a string. So what you need is.

```
my $hex = 0xFA1F;
my $bin = sprintf("%b", $hex);
print $bin;
```

Technical note:
Yes I know that Perl stores all its numbers internally as binary, but lets not go there for this answer, OK?

Comment: Re "*Perl converts them all to decimal*", No. Perl converts them to a format the computer understands (2's complement). Conversion to decimal (a text representation of a number) is done by `print`.

Comment: @ikegami See technical note at the bottom of the answer, I didn't want to confuse the questioner.

Comment: I'd say a completely wrong explanation is more likely to confuse than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with using a distribution, I wrote [Bit::Manip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bit::Manip) to make my prototyping a bit easier when dealing with registers (There's also a [Pure Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bit::Manip::PP) version available if you have problems compiling the XS code).

Not only can it fetch out bits from a number, it can toggle, clear, set etc:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Bit::Manip qw(:all);

my $register = 0xFA1F;

# fetch the bits from register using msb, lsb

my $msbyte = bit_get($register, 15, 8);

print "value: $msbyte\n";

print "bin: " . bit_bin($msbyte) . "\n";

# or simply:
# printf "bin: %b\n", $msbyte;
```

Output:

```
value: 250
bin: 11111010
```

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steve_bertrand/2017/01/bit-string-manipulation-made-easy-with-bitmanip.html) I wrote that shows how to use some of the software's functionality with an example datasheet register.

Comment: this seams great, unforntunately I won't be able to download the library on my computer. Thank you for the answer though

Comment: @SLP  But you can download it!  The link "Pure Perl" version is a single file, which seems to have no dependencies (doesn't itself use any special libraries), and which can directly be `use`d in a Perl program.  So you can literally download that file and put it wherever you keep your own modules. And that's that, use it.  You can also see the [module code](https://metacpan.org/release/Bit-Manip-PP/source/lib/Bit/Manip/PP.pm) (less than 200 lines!), and use that as you see it fit!  I'm certain that the author won't mind :)

Comment: @zdim Nope, I certainly don't mind at all! It's the reason I publish all my code with the Perl license :)